# Change disabled input text text color in Opera

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, opera

Tried to find an answer, but I guess my search skills needs a makeover. Anyways:

I am doing some styling to a text field (input) when it's disabled. Basically I'm making the background dark gray and the font color white. This works perfectly (Safari needed a `-webkit-text-fill-color` property in addition to `color: white;`) - **but opera is not listening to me!**

No matter what I do, where I do it, and how I do it, the font color is still a pretty dark gray (which I assume is the standard color). If I remove the disabled-attribute, everything works perfectly.

excerpt of my CSS styling for the disabled style:

```
#customerNumberSearch[disabled="disabled"],
#customerNumberSearch:disabled {
    color: white;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: white;
}
```

So, how do you change the font color of a disabled input field in Opera?

---

**Edit - alternative solution**: This problem can be circumvented by changing out the disabled-attribute for `readonly`. This has some side effects, however, so make sure this works for you. A nice side effect is that this also fixes the problem in <= IE9

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
input[disabled] { color: red;}
```

Comment: You can try adding `color: red !important;`. Maybe it's overwritten by Opera's standard otherwise?

Comment: I've tried different combinations of `!important`, but even if I add these properties after the web site has rendered (through the console or developer plugin), it still doesn't change its color. Only thing that actually gets me the result I expect is if I remove the disabled attribute in its entirety.

Answer (score 0):

Can u try one of these:

```
[disabled] {
    color:#fff;
}
```

OR

```
#customerNumberSearch[disabled] {
    color:#fff !important;
}
```

Comment: I can't do the general styling (since this is a special case on a very large portal site), but your second idea did not work, unfortunately.

Comment: Just to let u know, opera is moving on to webkit engine for the next version, so all -webkit- vendor prefixes will work in future opera. I will let u know if i find a solution